# problem when drawing fast. Touching two point one after the another?

Tags: iphone

I created painting application...

Every thing drawing prefect..

Problem is when i running application in my mobile.

i am touching at point, and releasing the point...  and touching another point and release another point.. while continuously doing same thing.

its get drawn line in between both point.

what to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you watching both `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled`?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not record the inbetween points, your application will only create a line between the start and end. In order to get a line that curves to your tracing, you need to add an event for touchesMoved. Here is some psuedo-code of event handlers that is needed to create a drawing app.

```
  - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    //Record your first point here
    CGPoint point = [ [touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    //Record another point
    CGPoint point = [ [touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    //Call your rendering function
    [self draw];
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Record another point
    CGPoint point = [ [touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    //Call your rendering function
    [self draw]
    //Add any finishing code here
}
```

Comment: Ginamin...thanks ... i did the way you said........  I need not included the touchesCancelled..  testing my application.. when i touch it get drawn ...... when i touch another point it get drawn..... when i moved from one point to another point its drawn good...... now problem is .... when i touch and point and releasing and touching another point releasing    the same may doing continuously doing ... it suddenly gets line draw in between two points.

Comment: Are you storing your touches? Sounds like it. If so, when you finish with touchesEnded, clear out you array of points.

Comment: No i am not storing touches sir.

Comment: When i touches.. two different points in my view. with a small time gap a line is drawn automatically between them......when i am doing continuously it is happening.

Comment: Haha, no need to say sorry. :)